# Want to implement interthread communication in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am developing automation suite in python, with thought that come to my mind is after certain time,my automation suite should be stopped or in other words automation suite need to complete its execution in stipulated time. So my idea would be launching main program, it will create two threads 1. Automation suite and 2. Timer thread. so as long as time lapsed my second thread will stopped first automation thread.
Below is sample code which probably fulfill above requirements,

```
import threading
import time

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        if self.threadID==1:
            self.timeout(60)            
        else:
            self.Automation_Suite("XYZ")
        print "Exiting " + self.name

    def timeout(self,delay):        
        while delay!=0:
            time.sleep(1)
            delay=delay-1

    def Automation_Suite(self,name):
        count=500000
        while count!=0:
            print name
            count=count-1

# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1")
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2")

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
if not thread1.is_alive():
    thread2.join()

print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

But above code is not working, and looping infinite. so please suggest better solution which fulfill requirements?

Thanks,
Priyank Shah

Answer (score 0):

If I change `Automation_Suite` thus

```
def Automation_Suite(self,name):
    count=5
    while count!=0:
        print name, count
        count=count-1
```

I get this output

```
Starting Thread-1Starting Thread-2
XYZ 5
XYZ 4

XYZExiting Main Thread
 3
XYZ 2
XYZ 1
Exiting Thread-2
```

This appears to hang, but I think you are just being impatient. If I print the delay in the timeout function, I see it count down to 0, slowly.
It is tidier to just join each thread you start:

```
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```